# PHP string function in getting a specific line of a string in array string value

Tags: php, string, codeigniter, strtok

I would like to get a specific line of a string in a array string value. Example: **(Avelino Curato)avelinocurato@gmail.com**. In this example string, I want to get just the email address part of the string. I have tried using explode function but I dont want that it stored the string in parenthesis in array coz I will not use it anymore. I tried to use strtok, but strtok function seems to work perfectly when the string looks like this -> **avelinocurato@gmail.com(Avelino Curato)**. How would I able to utilize the strtok function to get the email addess part of the string in this string value **(Avelino Curato)avelinocurato@gmail.com** ? If not what other string function I will use to handle this? 
Here is my code and its corresponding output

```
function try_explode(){

$store_array = array();
$val = array(
'0' => 'avelinocurato@gmail.com(Avelino Curato)',
'1' => 'ferdinand2apploma.com(Ferdinand Balbin)'

);

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($val);$i++){

  $store_array[$i] = strtok($val[$i],')');

}

var_dump($store_array);
}
```

Output:

[image]

The output above is the result that I wanted to get, but how I would be able to get the same output with this array string value in place?

```
$val = array(
'0' => '(Avelino Curato)avelinocurato@gmail.com',
'1' => '(Ferdinand Balbin)ferdinand2apploma.com'

);
```

How I would be able to use strtok just to get email address part? If not, what other string function I may use for this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$val = '(Avelino Curato)avelinocurato@gmail.com';
$email = ltrim(strstr($val, ')'), ')');

echo $email; // avelinocurato@gmail.com
```

**[[ [DEMO](http://viper-7.com/edz9ug) ]]**

For the 2nd example you would not use `strtok()` as you want to get what is after the parentheses, so you would use `strstr()` to get the parentheses and anything after it, then you chop off the parentheses from the string.

If you want to be creative you can do this:

```
$val = '(Avelino Curato)avelinocurato@gmail.com';
//$val = 'avelinocurato@gmail.com(Avelino Curato)';
$email = strip_tags(strtr($val, '()', '<>'));

echo $email; // avelinocurato@gmail.com
```

**[[ [DEMO](http://viper-7.com/RzBF1p) ]]**

This will work in **both** cases, and does not require PHP to use the regex engine. It basically converts the opening and closing parentheses to opening and closing angle brackets which would then be considered a HTML tag, and then running strip tags will remove that portion. Simple, quick and easy to understand.

Comment: Wow.Thanks for this. Simple and clean way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'avelinocurato@gmail.com(Avelino Curato)';
if(preg_match('~^(.+?)\\((.+?)\\)$~', $string, $matches)){
    var_dump(array_map('trim', $matches));
}elseif(preg_match('~^\\((.+?)\\)(.+?)$~', $string, $matches)){
    var_dump(array_map('trim', $matches));
}
```

^ try this! **Regular Expressions are awesome.**

*PS*: **String tokenization** is... not meant for what you are doing! Keep your life simple, learn **RegEx**.

Comment: I already got the email add part given this example string => avelinocurato@gmail.com(Avelino Curato). The problem is this string value => (Avelino Curato)avelinocurato@gmail.com. Anyway, thanks for help.

Comment: @Avelino Fixed it for you. If one fails, try it flipped :)

Comment: If you are going to use a regex for this which would be slower and which you really shouldn't use unless you need complex pattern matching that PHP's string functions can't easily accomplish then you should use `preg_replace('/\([^)]+\)/', '', $str)` to just strip out the parentheses portion leaving the email behind. This will work for both situations. See [**demo**](http://viper-7.com/h1ojpV)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$val = array(
    '0' => '(Avelino Curato)avelinocurato@gmail.com',
    '1' => '(Ferdinand Balbin)ferdinand@apploma.com',
    '2' => 'ferdinand@apploma.com(Ferdinand Balbin)'

);

array_walk($val, function(&$value) { /* Use array walk to loop trough the array */

    $matches = array(); //create array to preserve matches after preg_match

    preg_match('/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.([A-Za-z0-9_-][A-Za-z0-9_]+)/', $value, $matches); 

    $value = $matches[0]; //set the [0] match in value
});

print_r($val);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my little example

```
function try_explode(){

    $store_array = array();
    $val = array(
        '0' => 'avelinocurato@gmail.com(Avelino Curato)',
        '1' => 'ferdinand2apploma.com(Ferdinand Balbin)'
    );

    foreach ($val as $key => $value) {
        $names[$key] = preg_replace("/.*\(([^\)]+)\)$/is", "\$1", $value);
        $emails[$key] = preg_replace("/^([^\(]+).*/is", "\$1", $value);
        $store_array[$key] = "(".$names[$key].") ".$emails[$key];
    }
    var_dump($names);
    var_dump($emails);
    var_dump($store_array);
}
```

Comment: You will can to have names and emails in different variables.

Comment: I already got the email add part given this example string => avelinocurato@gmail.com(Avelino Curato). The problem is this string value => (Avelino Curato)avelinocurato@gmail.com. Anyway, thanks for help.

Comment: oh, sorry for my inattention